# More than one answer to integration

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \sec^4(x)\tan(x)\,dx$$

For this question I use substitution method to solve but my answer was different (may be because of different approach).My answer was $(\sec^4x)/4 + C$. Can someone tell me if there are any other answers to this problem and how they are equivalent?

Comment: What are you integrating?

Comment: sec^4(x)tan(x)dx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint: Write your integrand as $$\tan(x)(\tan(x)^2+1)\sec(x)^2$$ and substitute $$u=\tan(x)$$ then we get $$\int u(u^2+1)du$$ and this is easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Write the integral as
$$
\int (1+\tan^2x)\tan x\sec^2x\, dx
$$
and make the substitution $u=\tan x$ to get that the integral equals
$$
\int u(1+u^2)\, du=\int u+u^3\, du
$$
which you should be able to integrate.